# Google Sheets IF function

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a function with the following criteria:

- if A2 is equal to A1 -> Text 1
- if A2 is empty -> Text 2
- if A2 is not empty and not equal to A1 -> Text 3

Something like connecting these two functions into one:

```
=if(A2=A1,"Text1","Text3")
=if(isblank(A2),"Text2")
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is combine your two formulas:

```
=if(isblank(A2),"Text2",if(A2=A1,"Text1","Text3"))
```